# Is there a way to run non-headless browser in TestCafe docker?

Tags: docker, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I'm running TestCafe docker and would like to see the browser so that I know what's happening and not run it in a headless mode by default. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

To run a browser in docker containers in non-headless mode, you need to start [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) and a window manager (e,g, [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/)) before starting TestCafe. These tasks are already completed in the official TestCafe docker image - [github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/tree/master/docker](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/tree/master/docker).

To see the browser, you need to access Xvbf's virtual display. To do this, use the VNC server. Please, refer to the following topic describing all three tasks in detail: https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8.