# Run a Testcafe Script on Chrome Headless in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, google-chrome, testing, kubernetes, testcafe

I have a Testcafe script (`script.js`). I want to run this on a Chrome browser, but in the headless mode. So, I use the following command.

```
testcafe chrome:headless script.js
```

This works fine. But, now I wish to Dockerize this and run it in a container. The purpose is to get this running in Kubernetes. How can I achieve this?

I see the [Testcafe Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/testcafe/testcafe/), but this is just to run a Testcafe instance. It does not cater to my requirement of running this script in a Chrome Headless in a container.

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776886/is-there-a-way-to-run-non-headless-browser-in-testcafe-docker) is different from what I am asking)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile), the `testcafe/testcafe` Docker image is based on the Alpine Linux image. It doesn't contain the `Chrome` browser, but you can run your tests using the `Chromium` browser.
More information can be found in this [documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/use-testcafe-docker-image.html)

> TestCafe provides a preconfigured Docker image with Chromium and Firefox installed.

---

#### Docker

I've created simple example for you to illustrate how it works.
On my local machine I have `tests` directory that contains one simple test script `script.js`:

```
root@server1:~# cat /tests/script.js 
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `First test`
    .page `http://google.com`;

test('Test 1', async t => {
        // Test code
});
```

I'm able to run this test script in container using below command:

```
root@server1:~# docker run -v /tests:/tests -it testcafe/testcafe chromium:headless /tests/script.js
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 86.0.4240.111 / Linux 0.0

 First test
 ✓ Test 1


 1 passed (1s)
```

#### Kubernetes

In addition you may want to run some tests in Kubernetes using for example `Jobs`.

I created `Dockerfile` based on `testcafe/testcafe` image that copies my test script to appropriate location and then built an image from this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM testcafe/testcafe
...
COPY tests/script.js /tests/script.js
...
```

Finally, I created `Job` using above image (it can be `CronJob` as well):

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: simple-test
spec:
  backoffLimit: 3
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <IMAGE_NAME>
        name: simple-test
        args: [ "chromium:headless", "/tests/script.js" ]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

As we can see `Job` successfully completed:

```
$ kubectl get job,pod
NAME                    COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/simple-test   1/1           18s        14m

NAME                    READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/simple-test-w72g2   0/1     Completed   0          14m
```

Comment: Works like a charm. What I tried was getting an Ubuntu Image, and installing everything from scratch, and ended up running the testcafe command. This saves all those complications

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)